# React native - display views with curved border between them

Tags: react-native

Any idea how can I create two views that fill the screen, with a curved border between them?
In the following example, the top one (red) should have a concave border, the other one (blue) a convex one?

[image]

Using the code suggested in the answer (60 instead of 60%, which doesn't work), gives the following:

[image]

Not what I am looking for, unfortunately...

Comment: Have you tried settings borderRadius to some ridiculous number like 30 or more?

Comment: Is this your only requirement? I will try to write a snack for you

Comment: @Woj Yes I did, couldn't get the above.

Comment: @Sarmad Well, there are components displayed in each, but once I set the views this way, I hope that this will work. No need for Snack, just paste sample code here.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code and check out.

```
<View>
    <View style={{width: "100%", height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <View style={{position:"absolute",top:50,width: "100%", height: 100, backgroundColor: 'steelblue',borderRadius:"60%"}} />
    <View style={{width: "100%", height: 100, backgroundColor: 'steelblue',}} />
</View>
```

The above code has a slight resemblence to what you want to achieve. However the best option would be to use image in the background.

Comment: I get an error for the borderRadius value: Error while updating property 'borderRadius' of a view managed by: RCTView; 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: instead of adding percentage value to borderRadius, pass number around 60.

Comment: thanks! Added your answer to my question. See above. Not what I am looking for, sorry...

Comment: have you tried giving larger values to borderRadius??. 90 or 100 may give a curve nearly to what you are expecting.

Comment: I have. Got nothing close to what I need

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer by Vishal in another Stack question: [Using SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645767/how-can-i-achieve-below-design-in-react-native)

RESULT:

[image: result]